Gradio in Python: updating dropdown choices with respect to another dropdown choice
The goal of my interface is to choose a college, department, and forecast years in order to plot data. However, when choosing a college, I can't seem to update the department values; when I choose social work in my college dropdown, i should be able to only see and choose the social work department and when I choose applied health sciences college in my college dropdown, I should get its departments in my department dropdown to choose from.
This is not happening and instead only the default/initial department values which where set using initial_department_choices = college_department_dict[first_college], are available to choose from; you can choose any college but the department dropdown will only have the first/default college's departments.
agr with agr departments
social work with agr departments
my update function doesn't seem to help either but it could be because I'm not familiar with gradio and using gradio Blocks.
Any tips on how to solve this problem?
def forecast(data, college_name, department_name, forecast_steps):
    xxxxx

with gr.Blocks() as demo2:
    # Define input components for Gradio interface
    college_department_dict = {
        'Agr, Consumer, & Environmental Sciences': ['Ag Ldrshp Educ Comm Program', 'Agr & Consumer Economics', 'Agr, Consumer, & Env Sci Admn',
                                                                                'Agr, Consumer, & Evn Sciences', 'Agricultural & Biological Engr', 'Agricultural Comm Pgm & Crse',
                                                                                'Animal Sciences', 'Crop Sciences', 'Food Science & Human Nutrition', 'Human Dvlpmt & Family Studies',
                                                                                'Natural Res & Env Sci'],
        'Applied Health Sciences': ['Applied Health Sci Courses', 'Applied Health Sciences Admin', 'i-Health Program', 'Kinesiology & Community Health',
                                    'Recreation, Sport and Tourism', 'Speech & Hearing Science'],
        'School of Social Work': ['School of Social Work']
        }



    ### This is where the dropdowns are assigned

    first_college = list(college_department_dict.keys())[0]
    initial_department_choices = college_department_dict[first_college]

    college_name_input = gr.Dropdown(college_department_dict.keys(), label="College Name")
    department_input = gr.Dropdown(initial_department_choices, label="Department")
    forecast_steps_input = gr.Slider(minimum=1, maximum=30, step=1, label="Forecast Steps",info="Choose how many years ahead to predict.")

    def update_departments(college_name):
        department_input.choices = college_department_dict[college_name]

    college_name_input.input(update_departments)




    def forecast_interface(college_name,department_name, forecast_steps):
        plot_figure = forecast(data, college_name, department_name, forecast_steps)
        return plot_figure


# Launch the Gradio interface
demo2 = gr.Interface(forecast_interface, 
            [college_name_input, department_input, forecast_steps_input], 
            gr.Plot())
demo2.launch()


I tried to make an update function that would be called that is called after college dropdown was chosen but the function does not seem to update the department dropdown choices.
